# AutoMapper with Join Query not working in C#

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I've just started using AutoMapper to map Database with Model. I've two tables and I've applied join between them. Also, I have created class which combines both the classes. Now I want to Auto Map this join result to variable.

```
var demo = db.bookings.Join(db.users, u => u.userId, j => j.userId, (u, j) => new { booking = u, user = j }).ToList();
var Lists = demo.Select(i=> Mapper.Map<UserBookingModel>(demo)).ToList();
return View(Lists);
```

I am getting 2 rows in Lists variable which is same as demo Variable but when I check inside the List variable I am getting null value as per you can see in below image:
[image] but if you see the demo variable, it shows the record

[image]

Comment: Post the mapping configuration.

Comment: in your `demo.Select` you send the entire demo-collection to the mapper, rather than the current item. `Map<T>(demo)` should probably be `Map<T>(i)`

Comment: @BarryO'Kane - I've not set any addition Mapping Configuration. it is default of omu.automapper

Comment: Are the properties to be mapped consistently named? Posting the entities and viewmodel code would be beneficial.

Comment: @J.Steen's advice work for me. it was very silly mistake of me... :(

Comment: @J.Steen's advice work for me. it was very silly mistake of me... :(

Answer (score 0):

assuming that "UserBookingModel" is really your destination class and not your source class,

you had a mistake sending the whole "demo" object to the mapper instead of each row

```
var demo = db.bookings.Join(db.users, u => u.userId, j => j.userId, (u, j) => new { 
booking = u, user = j }).ToList();
var Lists = demo.Select(i=> Mapper.Map<UserBookingModel>(i)).ToList();
return View(Lists);
```